# Swift 4 decodable json arrays

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

So I am currently woking on a program to parse a JSON Api which is linked at the bottom

When I run the code I get some output but not all [image: image of console output]

Mainly for the optional type of Anime which is good because it shows that it works but I also want to access the name and release date and languages however I have no idea how to work with JSON arrays like this in swift 4. I will attach my current code below.

```
import UIKit

struct AnimeJsonStuff: Decodable {
    let data: [AnimeDataArray]
}

struct AnimeDataArray: Decodable {
    let type: String?
}

class OsuHomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func jsonDecoding() {
        let jsonUrlString = "https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime"

        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return} //
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

            guard let data = data else {return}

            do {
                let animeJsonStuff =  try JSONDecoder().decode(AnimeJsonStuff.self, from: data)
                print(animeJsonStuff.data)

                let animeDataArray = try JSONDecoder().decode(AnimeDataArray.self, from: data)
                print(animeDataArray.type as Any)
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I have more code after that but it's just for setting up custom collectionViewCells.

Also here is the link to the [api](http://docs.kitsu.apiary.io/#reference/media/anime/fetch-collection?console=1)

Comment: What's the question? Also if this is about parsing a particular JSON string, please paste the string _into your question_; do not show _pictures_ of code, that does no one any good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please check below :

I din't add for all the keys. I added for some in `attributes`.

```
struct AnimeJsonStuff: Decodable {
    let data: [AnimeDataArray]
}

struct AnimeLinks: Codable {
    var selfStr   : String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case selfStr     = "self"
    }
}
struct AnimeAttributes: Codable {
    var createdAt   : String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case createdAt     = "createdAt"
    }
}
struct AnimeRelationships: Codable {
    var links   : AnimeRelationshipsLinks?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case links     = "links"
    }
}

struct AnimeRelationshipsLinks: Codable {
    var selfStr   : String?
    var related   : String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case selfStr     = "self"
        case related     = "related"
    }
}

struct AnimeDataArray: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let type: String?
    let links: AnimeLinks?
    let attributes: AnimeAttributes?
    let relationships: [String: AnimeRelationships]?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case type = "type"
        case links = "links"
        case attributes = "attributes"
        case relationships = "relationships"
    }
}
```

Json parsing :

```
func jsonDecoding() {
    let jsonUrlString = "https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return} //
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do {
            let animeJsonStuff =  try JSONDecoder().decode(AnimeJsonStuff.self, from: data)
            for anime in animeJsonStuff.data {
                print(anime.id)
                print(anime.type)
                print(anime.links?.selfStr)
                print(anime.attributes?.createdAt)
                for (key, value) in anime.relationships! {
                    print(key)
                    print(value.links?.selfStr)
                    print(value.links?.related)
                }
            }
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 28):

Answer for title "Swift 4 decodable json arrays"

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
   let array = try decoder.decode([YouCodableStruct].self, from: response.data!)
   debugPrint(array)
} catch {
   debugPrint("Error occurred")
}
```

http://andrewmarinov.com/parsing-json-swift-4/